# Unable to launch Apache Flink 1.11.1 in Windows 10 system by using ./bin/start-cluster.sh

Tags: apache-flink, startup

I have installed *apache_flink-1.11.1-bin-scala_2.11* in my windows System and also added **FLINK_HOME** in my environment variable. I also installed cygwin for Linux Environment in my Windows System. When I'm trying to launch flink by running `./bin/start-cluster.sh` it is unable to start the cluster. Error messages are coming as:

```
The execution result is empty
```

and

```
Could not get JVM Parameters and dynamic configurations properly.
```

Parameters under `flink-conf.yaml` are

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: 192.168.1.101
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
jobmanager.memory.process.size: 1600m
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1728m
parallelism.default: 1
```

with an additional one working node. I'm not able to debug the issue, please help me to sort out this configurational setup.

[image: Error image description here]

Comment: What are you setting FLINK_HOME to (are you sure that path can be found from within cygwin), and why do you set it in the first place? I'd also suggest to use 1.11.2 because this improves the error message.

Comment: Hi @ChesnaySchepler,I have tried with 1.11.2 scala version too but got no luck. Since FLINK_HOME is an environment parameter expected in the start-cluster.sh file, so I added it. But somehow the error still persists. Thanks though for your comments.

Comment: Flink determines FLINK_HOME automatically. Was the error message identical when you used 1.11.2?

Comment: After installation of flink 1.11.2 I got the error as :: [ERROR] Raw output from BashJavaUtils:/c/Program Files/flink-1.11.1-bin-scala_2.11/flink-1.11.2/bin/config.sh: line 483: C:\Program: No such file or directory alongwith [ERROR] The execution result is empty.
[ERROR] Could not get JVM parameters and dynamic configurations properly...                  @ChesnaySchepler

Comment: For the time being, move Flink somewhere where the absolute path has no space in it.  (i.e., don't put it under "Program Files")

Comment: Hey, I have tried running flink from downloads folder according to your comments. But same issue persists with the error: "/c/Users/ankits621/Downloads/flink-1.11.2/bin/config.sh: line 483: C:\Program: No such file or directory". Is it a problem with my java? @ChesnaySchepler

Comment: yes; java also has be available under a path without spaces. I guess this also explains why I couldn't reproduce the issue (Flink is supposed to support spaces in paths). I have filed a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19360